# I have more apps than my max storage

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, storage, app2sd

[image: Storage screenshot]

As you can see in the screen shot my device recognises I have ~.5 gig of storage left, but I have an impossible amount of apps. When I moved a 230 MB app from SD to phone the apps storage when from 5.18 GB to 5.15 GB. I was confused so am wondering if any of you Android Enthusiasts know what is going on, and how to solve this issue (assuming this is an issue)

**Edit:** Diskinfo

This is after I installed disk info so the numbers will be diffrent than my original screenshot

```
--------------------------
 Internal Storage (MMC)
--------------------------
 * System [mmcblk0p30] (/system) [ext4]
   Used: 1.2 GB, Free: 329 MB, Total space: 1.5 GB
 * Cache [mmcblk0p31] (/cache) [ext4]
   Used: 9.6 MB, Free: 290 MB, Total space: 300 MB
 * Data (userdata) [mmcblk0p32] (/data) [ext4]
   Used: 4.6 GB, Free: 555 MB, Total space: 5.1 GB
--------------------------
 SD Card
--------------------------
 * External SD [mmcblk1p1] (/mnt/media_rw/external_SD, /mnt/secure/asec, /storage/external_SD) [vfat]
   Used: 10.9 GB, Free: 18.4 GB, Total space: 29.3 GB
```

**Edit:** disk usage

[image: disk usage]

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage).